# How to distinguish "ipfs object links" "ipfs object stat" ? I mean the size of file

Tags: ipfs

I read at https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-object-links to figure out my problem.
I mean the method to calculate the size file.
[ipfs object stat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJbEk.png)
[ipfs object links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2E8p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at example: `QmdHY9TnXaXez2bSsQqanm2WaAineyiaFydwqqkEk6kyzs` is a directory with a single JPG file.

```
$ ipfs object links  /ipfs/QmdHY9TnXaXez2bSsQqanm2WaAineyiaFydwqqkEk6kyzs
QmbWqxBEKC3P8tqsKc98xmWNzrzDtRLMiMPL8wBuTGsMnR 119776 guardian.jpg

$ ipfs object stat  /ipfs/QmdHY9TnXaXez2bSsQqanm2WaAineyiaFydwqqkEk6kyzs
NumLinks: 1
BlockSize: 60
LinksSize: 58
DataSize: 2
CumulativeSize: 119836

$ ipfs object stat /ipfs/QmdHY9TnXaXez2bSsQqanm2WaAineyiaFydwqqkEk6kyzs/guardian.jpg
NumLinks: 0
BlockSize: 119776
LinksSize: 4
DataSize: 119772
CumulativeSize: 119776
```

- `119772` is the size of `guardian.jpg` (blocks with file data alone)
- `119776` is the size of `guardian.jpg` DAG (file data + DAG metadata)
- `119836` is the size of `guardian.jpg` DAG + metadata of wrapping directory under CID `QmdHY9TnXaXez2bSsQqanm2WaAineyiaFydwqqkEk6kyzs`

If you want to understand what "DAG" and "DAG metadata" is about, check:

- tutorials:

  - [Decentralized data structures](https://proto.school/#/data-structures)
  - [Files API](https://proto.school/#/regular-files-api)
- video course: [How IPFS Deals With Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5zNPwMDYGg)

Comment: Thank you @lidel, I was confused for a month, It's a part of my thesis research. Thank you very much again